# ZF2 create common lib for database access across all modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm starting with ZF2 and I have an application with multiple modules that are being treated as different 'sites'.  I want to have a common lib that handles all data access.

Ideally, I would create something like "common" in the root directory which holds entities, mappers and services.

I've done this, but I can't seem to get it to autoload the new namespace which is outside the context of the module.

I've tried using:

```
    Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'autoregister_zf' => true,
            'namespaces' => array(
                'Common' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/site/common',
            )
        )
    ));
```

Then I created the directory structure:

```
Common/Entity/User/User.php
Common/Mapper/User/User.php
```

But when I try to use these it doesn't find the files.

Any idea if there's a recommended or best practice for doing this - or how do accomplish what I'm doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The recommendation for best practice is to keep everything inside a module. Zf2 is modular application and services like data access should be part of a module as well. I would advise you too create this "common" structure as a module (below is a link of the ZF2 skeleton module).

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule

In the link bellow you will find some useful information about how to prepare your module and prepare the service manager from it, to provide those mappers and entities.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.module-manager.intro.html

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Stoyan,  We're using modules now, however, we have several facets of our site (admin, api, front-end, cms, etc) that are all different applications but for the same 'project'.  We've decided to seperate each of these into modules, then we can use the same project and share files.  Therefore, it would seem to pollute our module space by having non-sites within it, if that makes sense.

Comment: Although I have different opinion about the purpose of modules in applications than yours I can give you a suggestion how to deal with this. You can create a base module where you put all the functionality that would "pollute", as you said, your app structure :)